# Critical error when installing wordpress in xampp

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I have installed xampp in Windows 11. I started Apache and MySQL. I have download wordpress inside htdocs, unzip and renamed ¨ideas¨. I created a database in Mysql named ¨ideas¨. I open in the browset localhost/ideas it starts the wordpress asking me the country, the a form where I put database name ¨ideas¨, username ¨root¨, password empty and prefix of table ¨wp_¨, when I summit the form I get a critical error and I cannot continue with the wordpress setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Will I tried And YAY!! therefor see the solution that i come with:

**1-** Go to [Download WordPress from HERE!!!!!!](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/installer) then **under On my computer** select win/mac/Linux then go down and download the one that work with your operating system.

**2-** Then install **It's simple**

 **Noties:** WordPress will install phpmyadmin and Apache, therefor it will not need Xampp. **It's a stand alone**

**3-** copy the wordpress files from the installation

> **C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.8.3-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs**
>
> To
> **C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress**

and then edit the wp-config.php in xampp copied wordpress.

in the wp-config.php

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'bitnami_wordpress' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'bn_wordpress' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'Go_Hacker_Nothing_to_see_here XD' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

/** Database charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The database collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```

save it.

**-4** edit the User's and the GRANT in the xampp phpMyAdmin
Login then go to DB called phpmyadmin => PRIVILEGES => new User
[image: PRIVILEGES]

add the user you saw in define( 'DB_USER', '**bn_wordpress**' );
and then add the same paswoord you putted in **wp-config.php** => **Go_Hacker_Nothing_to_see_here XD**

**5-** go to wordpress phpmyadmin, for me it was http://127.0.0.1:81/phpmyadmin/

Login as root + the password that you set on wordpress installation.

Go to Database bitnami_wordpress then export as .sql then go.
[image: export]

**6-** go to xampp phpmyadmin Login as root or whatever then add new Database and call it as same as in the wp-config.php  define( 'DB_NAME', '**bitnami_wordpress**' );

With this database selected go to import "Next to export" and select the .sql file from your downloads folder.

**-7** edit the port in table= wp_options for **home** and **siteurl**
or just put them as http://localhost/wordpress/

**8-** with the bitnami_wordpress database selected go to PRIVILEGES then the wordpress user that you created select edit-PRIVILEGES
then go to Database next to global and select the database you created for wordpress and press go. then select all and go.

[image: edit-PRIVILEGES]

[image]

**9-** in the wp-config.php edit this

> define('WP_TEMP_DIR',
> 'C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.8.3-0/apps/wordpress/tmp');
>
> To
> define('WP_TEMP_DIR', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\temp');

**Dont forget to create the file there**

**10-** Go To http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin
Login with the setup username and password, and delete all post in there!

**11-** Go to sittings then permalink and set **Common Settings** to **Plain**

**BTW:**WordPress Can Not be Installed With Xampp higher than **8.0.14**

So if you want it to be with xampp [Download 8.0.14](https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/8.0.14/xampp-windows-x64-8.0.14-1-VS16-installer.exe) and then do what you did in your question. If you dont want to do all 11 steps.

**BTW:** you can uninstall wordpress we dont need it anymore

If you want to ask why all of that!!. i will till you because the MySQL server from the wordpress instalation is extremly slow and you dont want to run 2 port and 2 MySQL

**Let me know what you got :)**